# java 8 streams reduce method returns same result

Tags: stream

Having java code like this:

```
public static void main(String... aa) {
    Stream<Integer> stream = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).stream();
    List<Integer> numbers = stream.reduce(
            new ArrayList<Integer>(),
            (List<Integer> l, Integer e) -> {
                l.add(e);
                return l;
            },
            (List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) -> {
                l1.addAll(l2);
                return l1;
            });
    System.out.println("numbers" + numbers);

    stream = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).stream();
    numbers = stream.reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>(),
            (List<Integer> l, Integer e) -> {
                l.add(e);
                return l;
            },
            (List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) -> {
                return l1;
            });
    System.out.println("numbers" + numbers);

    stream = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).stream();
    numbers = stream.reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>(),
            (List<Integer> l, Integer e) -> {
                l.add(e);
                return l;
            },
            (List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) -> {
                return null;
            });
    System.out.println("numbers" + numbers);
}
```

gives result as this:

numbers[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

numbers[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

numbers[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

why the result it is same ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the aswer is:
When a stream executes in parallel, the Java runtime splits the stream into multiple substreams. In such cases, we need to use a function to combine the results of the substreams into a single one. This is the role of the combiner — in the above snippet, it's the Integer::sum method reference.

so the proper implementation is the first one.